# clonenode script not execute in firefox

Tags: javascript, clonenode

why clonenode script does not execute in firefox. it works fine in chrome?

`<script id="myscript" src='myscript.js' type='text/template'></script>`

I am cloning it by replacing the `type='text/template'` to `'text/javascript'`

```
const existing = document.querySelector("#myscript");
const newScript = existing.cloneNode();
newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
existing.replaceWith(newScript);
```

what can be the reason?

Comment: This seems like an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why are you doing this?

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that Firefox is cloning the flag saying that that script has been processed, but Chrome isn't. (I've been able to replicate your result.)

To do this reliably, create a new element instead:

```
const existing = document.querySelector("#myscript");
const newScript = document.createElement("script");
newScript.src = existing.src;
newScript.type = "text/javascript"; // Or just leave this line out, JavaScript is the default.
existing.replaceWith(newScript);
```

Comment: Thanks but how will it work with querySelectorAll?

Comment: @Uxair - I don't see how `querySelectorAll` relates to the question...?